# PowerPivot SQL to Access databases

Tags: sql, ms-access, union, powerpivot

I need to union tables into PowerPivot from 6 Access Databases that are currently on a network drive.

PowerPivot gives me the option to pull the data using SQL code but I have not found any examples online as to the syntax.

Basically wanting to do

```
SELECT * FROM path [DB01].[TBL01]
UNION
SELECT * FROM path [DB02].[TBL01]
UNION
SELECT * FROM path [DB03].[TBL01]
UNION
SELECT * FROM path [DB04].[TBL01]
UNION
SELECT * FROM path [DB05].[TBL01]
UNION
SELECT * FROM path [DB06].[TBL01]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add paths in brackets:

```
SELECT * FROM [C:\Path\To\DB01.accdb].[TBL01]
UNION
SELECT * FROM [C:\Path\To\DB02.accdb].[TBL01]
UNION
SELECT * FROM [C:\Path\To\DB03.accdb].[TBL01]
UNION
SELECT * FROM [C:\Path\To\DB04.accdb].[TBL01]
UNION
SELECT * FROM [C:\Path\To\DB05.accdb].[TBL01]
UNION
SELECT * FROM [C:\Path\To\DB06.accdb].[TBL01]
```